# Why is my lucky bamboo turning yellow?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, containers, fertilizer, lucky-bamboo

I have a wrapping of bamboo stalks, maybe 20 or so stalks tied together. 3 or 4 stalks have died one at a time the past 2 months - they start to get yellow-greenish, then more yellow over time. The rest of the stalks seem totally fine (even right next to them). I've had it about a year, it was fine for 6 months or so.

Things I've tried:

- Use only room temperature distilled water
- Wash out the roots and scrub container (no chemicals)
- Less light
- More light
- Inspect for fungus/bugs
- Remove yellowing stalk and soak the whole thing in water to try to propagate it (it just rotted)

Pics of lighting situation, pot, etc (late afternoon, it's generally brighter in the day but not super bright): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA8be.jpg

Last things I'm considering are:

- Use some kind of fertilizer (one answer stated this? [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004490QYI/ref=cm_sw_su_dp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004490QYI))
- Get a magnifying glass to check for tiny bugs
- Change the pot up (either bigger with pure water, or plant it in dirt, but this feels risky since only 1 stalk dies at a time..)
- Take a healthy one and try to make many clones of it just in case it does die
- Do something about the roots? I have heard that them having a tangle of roots is actually normal, but it does look root-bound.

This plant is sentimental so I want to try my best.

Comment: Please read some of these current threads, and see if they answer your question: 

 [Why has our lucky bamboo turned yellow?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/why-has-our-lucky-bamboo-turned-yellow) 
 
 [What is killing off my lucky bamboo?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16230/what-is-killing-off-my-lucky-bamboo) 

  [Can I fix my lucky bamboo that has yellow stalks?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/can-i-fix-my-lucky-bamboo-that-has-yellow-stalks)

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at all these already and have researched a few hours. Every resource I have seen indicates that the whole plant will go under, ie if temperature is too low, nutrients are bad, fungus, sunburn, etc - but only 1 of the many plants dies at a time despite being in the exact same proximity. Perhaps nutrient competition? Don't see many bound like this though I found some on amazon with good reviews.

Comment: Have you ever used fertilizer, at all?

Comment: No I haven't, I've only read advice to not use fertilizer, and only once seen someone suggest to use it, so I hadn't tried. Is there one you recommend I should try? Or are you wondering if it could be burned?

Comment: The plants do need some nutrients in the long run, or they won't be able to keep up the photosynthesis, making food

Comment: Cleaning the water every couple weeks, and adding a highly diluted general purpose soluble fertilizer would be a start...